# Association between has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, associations, belongs-to

In an example database, associations are as follows: an Owner has_many homes and Home belongs_to Owner. I know I can call owner.homes to get a list of all their homes but in my View I only seem to be able to call the home.owner_id to get anything from the owner object.

Is there a way to get around this?

Home model:

```
belongs_to :owner, 
 inverse_of: :homes
```

params look like

```
def home_params
    params.require(:home).permit(:street_address, :city, :state, :postal_code, :description, :owner_id)
  end
```

Comment: are you trying to get a transitive relation?

Comment: Not quite sure but after a quick google search on that term I think so

Comment: Maybe you can look for the solution now.. Comment back in case unsuccessful

Comment: @AkshatSinghal Hm, I tried some research to no avail. In my View I only seem to be able to call the home.owner_id to get anything from the Owner object. I'd like to get the owner.first_name instead. Is there a way to achieve this in my view. Perhaps a change to my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to do `home.owner` is a natural outcome of what you've described, just as is `owner.homes`. This is all covered in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

If you can do `home.owner_id`, but not `home.owner`, that means that your database is set up properly, but you're missing the `belongs_to :owner` call in your `Home` model.

Comment: I edited my question accordingly. I only seem to be able to call the home.owner_id in my view to get anything from the owner object. Is there a way around this? Is there something I need to do with the params?

Comment: I rechecked and I have the following:       belongs_to :owner,
  inverse_of: :homes

Comment: Are you calling `home.owner` and getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: Note that `owner_id` is in the `Home` object, not the `Owner` object. To get `first_name`, for example, you need to do `home.owner.first_name`, not, `home.first_name`.

Comment: Ok I may know what's going on now. Will try things out in a revised test. Thanks. Yea it was just my test not working properly…Everything else good. Thanks again